# Zepto.js Slider or jQuery Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

Is there any slider that can work with Zepto.js instead of jQuery and has support for touch events provided by Zepto?

Should I stick with jQuery and trigger the slider touch events with plugins like hammer.js http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/

Since jQuery it's on google's CDN I don't think download time is an issue.

Did anybody used zepto.js succesfuly in a mobile web project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, that's a number of different questions. Here goes:

**1 & 2)**
There are a number of sliders/carousels that support touch events by default, such as [FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/). FlexSlider, like many jQuery plugins or extensions, requires jQuery. However, since Zepto is API-compatible with jQuery, most likely FlexSlider will work out of the box with jQuery. I'd simply search through the code for references to jQuery and change to Zepto or $. However, FlexSlider currently has a [Win 8 bug](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/519) which might make it a non-starter for you. In which case I'd recommend using the popular Bootstrap carousel and plugging in your own touch events, as described in the [this article](http://lazcreative.com/blog/how-to/how-to-adding-swipe-support-to-bootstraps-carousel/). The post describes how to use jQuery Mobile touch events, yet it would be just as easy to use Zepto touch events. Inversely, if you'd like to use Zepto touch events with jQuery, this is also easy to accomplish. It requires a couple minor modifications (you can grab my patched up version [here](http://endless.beautifuluniquesnowflake.com/assets/js/plugins/jquery.zepto-touch.js)).

**3)** 
While [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) does not host Zepto, you can find it hosted on [Cloudflare's cdnjs](http://cdnjs.com/). There's even suggestion that [cdnjs may be faster than Google CDN](http://www.baldnerd.com/make-your-site-faster-cloudflares-cdnjs-vs-google-hosted-libraries-shocking-results/).

**4)**
Yes, I've used Zepto in mobile projects. It works well and is a fair bit lighter than jQuery, which provides backwards compatibility that is mostly unnecessary on mobile devices.